# May one graduate in a multi-purpose church building?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

Suppose a school graduation is held in a building that is used for church services as well as various kinds of non-religious cultural events. One example of such a venue is the  [United Palace theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Palace); which [bills itself](https://www.unitedpalace.org/) as a "interfaith spiritual center, entertainment venue, and artistic hub." Is it permissible to attend a graduation in such a place?

Comment: Similar to this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/voting-in-a-church/31982#31982 and here's a also Reddit thread which discusses this scenario https://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/4cscol/halachic_question_columbia_universitys_teachers/

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough in Halacha and I can't provide sources but I can assure you 100% that a Jew is forbidden to enter a church because it's a place of Avodah Zarah.

Comment: See https://s3.amazonaws.com/ncsy-education/Headlines%20-%20Touring%20the%20Vatican%20and%20Viewing%20its%20Artwork.pdf

Comment: @DanWeisberg That's not 100% clear in this question. A rabbi clarified for me once that halachically, a "neutral" building that is used occasionally for "Church services" is technically not a Church. As I understand it, OP says that this place "doubles as a Church". Meaning, it fits what I just described. Thus, while it is not functioning as a Church per se, it's just a theater.

Comment: What do you mean by "to graduate"? I graduated when the registrar of my school reviewed my file and clicked a button. I wasn't there nor do I know when it happened.

Comment: therxv, if this situation pertains to you, I recommend consulting with your rabbi, possibly armed with information from answers posted here. Mi Yodeya [can't advise you what to do](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Answer (score -3):

*For the practical rule please consult your Rabbi.*

The main prohibition of visiting a church is indirect - it *might look* as if one converted or worships idols. In a situation where the place is commonly, publicly and openly used for social events, such fear does not exist and therefore it would not be prohibited.

Another consideration is "what's at stake?", we usually tend to leniency when monetary (or other significant) losses are at stake. Like if you dropped a $100 bill in front of a Buddha statue you're allowed to pick it up or enter a church to demand to pay debts.

Only in some extreme cases, for example, when a prominent Rabbi is involved or when the ceremony requires elements of worshipping it should be reconsidered.

Comment: Would be great if you could provide sources

Comment: I believe this post is wrong. There's a separate prohibition of going into a foreign place of worship, for any reason, such as voting or touring