# Halacha Regarding Entering a Church

Tags: halacha, christianity, music, parnassah-livelihood

It would be very much appreciated if someone can provide some sources that permit a Jew to enter a church premises (not the actual sanctuary). I've signed up for a classical guitar festival that's in a church, but does not take place in the sanctuary, but rather other rooms within the church's building. This is an activity which would greatly benefit my career should I go, and it's not hosted by the church, but rather a separate organization. I've asked a Rabbi in person, who said yes, but I struggle to find sources. Additionally, would passing through the sanctuary to make it to another room be mutar? Thank you!

Comment: Why not ask the Rabbi for sources?

Comment: This I recieved from a (neolog) rabbi who entered... https://guardyoureyes.com/articles/12-step/item/is-it-permissible-to-enter-a-church-to-attend-a-12-step-meeting

Comment: I can't ask because it's night time and I need to know soon!

Comment: Thank you Binyomin!!! I don't know how you guys on here find things so expediently!

Comment: TY Yehoshua. How is your name Yehoshua K (same as R. Kaganoff)? Crazy coincidence. It seems this ruling doesn't even specify about a sanctuary, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Dovid it explicitly states you cannot enter the sanctuary for any reason

Comment: Ok I see does indeed specify. I'm kind of skimming right now. But doesn't it say you may enter a sanctuary when no services are taking place?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/voting-in-a-church

Comment: There are many sources to explore here: https://rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Entering-Churches-and-Mosques-Part-2.pdf friendly reminder however that Mi Yodeya is not intended to replace the personalized advice of your rabbi: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi

Comment: The OP asked a Rabbi and received permission - so it seems he is not asking for a psak. He asks us to "provide some sources". Therefore this question should not be closed.

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/66072.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Voting in a church?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/voting-in-a-church)

Comment: I once went into the Church of Nativity in Bethlehem and set fire to the grotto during the Pope's visit there. I guess this is allowed as according to my understanding you can go in to smash their idols.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my findings it should be prohibited.

The חכמת אדם פ"ד, ט"ז explains that because an Avodah Zara is assur behana'a (one is not allowed to have any enjoyment from it) one can not enter the house of an Avodah Zara and to look at its beauty. There is even a Mitzvah to not walk with 4 Amos of its entrance.

Because Christians believe in שיתוף they are considered ovdei avoda Zara.

Accordingly, Rabbi Ovadia ( יחווה דעת ד,מ"ה) rules that one is forbidden to enter  a church.

For further reference see

- Article by Rabbi Shmuel Shapira here [enter link description here](https://m.ynet.co.il/articles/4295175)
- Hidabroot article [here](https://www.hidabroot.org/article/2681)

Comment: do the rooms outside the church sanctuary have the din of a beis avoda zara?

Comment: @ezra at a minimum it wouldn't be better than the 4 Amos in front of the entrance

Comment: churches can be quite large. it's possible the room will not be within 4 amos. i've also seen churches with such rooms with entrances on the outside of the establishment so entrance into the church's front doors is not necessary